# how to get a data where the rows of a table have been added for the same IDs in the columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Symbol, SubsectorDescription, MarketValue, Quantity 
FROM [PM].[dbo].[ViewPCData] 
WHERE  Objective = 'Stocks' 
   AND SectorDescription != 'NULL' 
   AND SubsectorDescription != 'NULL'
```

This code gives me a list of the fields I want. I intend to query a table where given the same Symbol and SubsectorDescription value in two rows, the MarketValue and Quantity of these two rows should get added and be returned in one row of the table.

Comment: In other words what is the equivalent of plyr::summarize in SQL?

Comment: Do you really have the string literal "NULL" in your database? And what is plyr::summarize??

Comment: Please google and learn about `GROUP BY` and `Aggregation in SQL Server`

Comment: @TabAlleman Thank you! That helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you aren't utilizing string literal `NULLs` in your database (you shouldn't be), I believe you may be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
    Symbol
    ,SubsectorDescription
    ,SUM(MarketValue) AS 'MarketValueSum'
    ,SUM(Quantity) AS 'QuantiySum'
FROM
    [PM].[dbo].[ViewPCData] 
WHERE
    Objective = 'Stocks' 
    AND SectorDescription IS NOT NULL
    AND SubsectorDescription IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    Symbol
    SubsectorDescription
```